# apply jquery filter to an created div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey guys i was wondering if someone could help with some issues on my code.

Basically ive created 4 elements(divs) in an onclick event.From html i've also done so that same button dissapears

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="blackjack2.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="blackjack1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button class= "boton" id="start">Play</button>
<button class= "boton" id="hit">Hit</button>
<button class= "boton" id= "stand">Stand</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

var jugar = document.getElementById('start')
var mas = document.getElementById('hit')
var mantener = document.getElementById('stand')


var cuerpo= document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]

var crear_cartas= function() {
var card= document.createElement('div');
var texto =document.createTextNode("CASINO");
card.setAttribute("class","cartas");
card.appendChild(texto);
cuerpo.appendChild(card);
}

jugar.onclick= function(){
crear_cartas()
crear_cartas()
crear_cartas()
crear_cartas()
jugar.setAttribute('class','ocultar')
}
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Up to there is ok , but im not sure if from jquery i can apply a filter that activates on the same onclick event that appears in javascript code (on those 4 created elements )to the even ones so that they make an animation lowering slightly the margin. 
I've read about it but i am a bit at sea given that the filter would apply to created elements..
Thank you in advance guys

css class ".cartas" code included:

```
.cartas{
/*display: none;*/
margin: 260px 75px 0 75px;
display: inline-block;
border-radius: 10px;
border: 1px  solid black;
padding-top: 50px;
height:100px;
width:100px;
color: #003366;
font-family: Muli,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif;
text-align: center;
background-color: #f0f8ff;
}
```

Comment: you would like the even number of elements with label "CASINO", when clicked, use a margin bottom to shift down the element below it?

Comment: Yes! as long as the animation simply moves the even divs created that would be great  , doesnt matter the direction , thank you for your help repzero

Comment: Okay.. check my response

Answer (score 0):

Add an onlcick event to all event divs. This event will add a class that will push the elements below those divs downward using a margin-bottom

Snippet below

```js
var counter = 0;
var jugar = document.getElementById('start')
var mas = document.getElementById('hit')
var mantener = document.getElementById('stand')


var cuerpo = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]

var crear_cartas = function() {
  card = document.createElement('div');
  var texto = document.createTextNode("CASINO");
  card.setAttribute("class", "cartas");
  card.appendChild(texto);
  cuerpo.appendChild(card);
}

jugar.onclick = function() {
  for (var x = 0; x < 4; ++x) {
    crear_cartas();
    if ((x + 1) % 2 == 0) {
      card.addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.classList.add("move");
      })

    }

  }
  jugar.setAttribute('class', 'ocultar')
} //end func
```

```css
div {
  transition: margin-bottom 0.5s;
}

.move {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="blackjack2.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="blackjack1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <button class="boton" id="start">Play</button>
  <button class="boton" id="hit">Hit</button>
  <button class="boton" id="stand">Stand</button>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work , seems that might be interfeering with the line of code 
card.setAttribute("class", "cartas") 
Modified your line of code to adjust it to the existing class but still didn't worked (simply increased top margin)
I included css class .cartas in the code